# Three.js twist plane like DNA strand

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Im trying to twist a plane to make it look like a spiral or DNA shape (ps. its not to actually use as a DNA strand).

Ive got a dotted plane showing at the moment but cannot work out how to twist the plane at all.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njL9rrne/1/

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true 
    });
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1);
    //var gui = new dat.GUI();
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    var texture = (function() {
      var w = 16, h = 16;
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
      // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      canvas.width = w; canvas.height = h;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(w / 2, h / 2, 0, w / 2, h / 2, w / 2);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, '#ffffff');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.2, '#ffffff');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.4, '#ffffff');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');
      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      return texture;
    }());

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(500, 100, 100, 25);

    var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff,
      alphaTest: 0.5,
      size: 5,
      transparent: true,
      map: texture
    });

    var pointCloud = new THREE.PointCloud(geometry, material);
    pointCloud.sortParticles = true;
    scene.add(pointCloud);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var step = 0;
    var render = function() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

      step += 0.004;
      pointCloud.rotation.x = step;
      // pointCloud.rotation.z = step;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);

    };

    var resize = function() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

    resize();
    render();
```